# Percentage Calculation Problem

Tags: percentages

I have some financial reports, I can see user deposits of:

£12.90

But actually, the real deposit is £15, but because of fees which I've worked out is 14%, it brings it down to £12.90.

On my report I can see numerous deposits such as

```
£12.90
£8.60
```

But when I try to add 14% on to these values it doesn't give me the correct answer

```
e.g. 14% of £12.90 = £1.80 + £12.90 = £14.70
```

How would I do the calculation from the deposits in my report to get the correct answer.

I hope this is explained well.

Comment: The $14\%$ is taken off the total, not the discounted value.  Thus, given $12.90$ you should divide by $1-.14=.86$.  (and $\frac {12.9}{.86}=15$ as desired).

Comment: That works perfectly - but is where has the .14 come from?

Comment: $14\%$ is $.14$.  After all $.14\times100=14$.

Comment: Dam, now I feel stupid - thanks for explaining this for me

Comment: The way the algebra sorts out:  you start with $x$ and remove $14\%$ of it, thus retaining $x-.14x=(1-.14)x=.86x$.  You are then told that this is $12.9$ so we have $.86x=12.9\implies x = \frac {12.9}{.86}=15$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have $12.90$ pounds then they are  equal to $86\%$. $14\%$ have been already subtracted (from $100\%$).

To get $100\%$ you have to divide $12.90$ by $86$. Now you have $1\%$ from $100\%$.

The result has to be multiplied it by $100$ to get $100\%$.

$12.90\cdot \frac{100}{86}=15.00$

$15$ pounds are equivalent to $100\%$